# IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.<init>()

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

Using Avro for serializing data to byte[] and deserializing data. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AVRO/FAQ#FAQ-HowcanIserializedirectlyto/fromabytearray? shows sample usage.

```
SpecificDatumReader<User> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<User>(User.getClassSchema());
```

The above line is causing the following error

```
IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.<init>() from class com.abc.schema.generated.User
```

Any pointers to what might be going wrong here? No errors seen at compile time.

Comment: Confluent already provides Avro serializers for Kafka. Are you trying to write your own?

Comment: Not using schema registry in my case. Will those work even if schema registry is not used?

Comment: This should work, although, I don't see it frequently being done in Kafka.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to you having an older version of Avro in your classpath. To check, run your program with the `-verbose:class` parameter and look for instance of `SpecificData` in the output. Example:

```
 java -verbose:class -jar your_jar.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the class loading from parent-first to child-first fixed this for me